# Should the group decisions be independent in Wilcoxon rank sum test?

Tags: nonparametric, independence, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

In case you want to compare the average income of a group of male employees against the average income of a group of female employees, the observations are clearly independent.

Now, I have a network of a certain number of nodes. These nodes are linked by edges and I can characterize each node by the number of links it has to other nodes. (this is $k$: called the degree)
I can also characterize the nodes by their average nearest neighbour degree. That is the sum of the degree of all nodes, to which one node is linked to. (this is $k_{nn}$; $k_{nn}$ of node i = $\sum k_j$ for any node $j$ that is linked to $i$).

When I create a scatter plot of these nodes ($k$ vs $k_{nn}$) I can clearly distinguish two groups of nodes by a certain threshold value for $k$ and $k_{nn}$.

My nodes also have a color. Now I want to test if a certain color in these two groups is overrepresented.
I can do that using the Wilcoxon rank test, because the color is an independent observation. Fine.

But is the color really an independent observation?
Implicitly the association to a group is not only based on the node's own property, but also on the properties of the other nodes (because of $k_{nn}$).

So can I really use the Wilcoxon rank test here?

Actually, my question is:
Does the Wilcoxon rank test require only an independent observation.
Or does it also require an association to a group that is based on independent observations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of the graph's coloring, associated with each of its nodes is a pair $(k, k_{nn})$.  You have used these pairs to classify the nodes into two groups.  The coloring separately classifies the nodes by color.  This is the situation of a $c$ by $2$ contingency table with fixed margins.  To assess whether color is associated with node group, use an appropriate test of association: [Fisher's Exact Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) if the counts are not too large; otherwise a chi-squared test.